# Clipboard does not copy URL properly

Tags: macos, big-sur, copy-paste, web-browser, url

I am trying to copy this url:

```
https://preview.themeforest.net/item/byron-construction-and-engineering-wordpress-theme/full_screen_preview/28520387?_ga=2.75926102.272258780.1641055757-495160342.1640239713&amp;_gac=1.183025236.1641058506.Cj0KCQiAlMCOBhCZARIsANLid6agL3jaSAir1_krVJwUfbyNOb4FdawehBgKdBLPg-pXSqElt6vrEmQaAukMEALw_wcB
```

but after copying the url,  `amp;` gets omitted:

https://preview.themeforest.net/item/byron-construction-and-engineering-wordpress-theme/full_screen_preview/28520387?_ga=2.75926102.272258780.1641055757-495160342.1640239713&_gac=1.183025236.1641058506.Cj0KCQiAlMCOBhCZARIsANLid6agL3jaSAir1_krVJwUfbyNOb4FdawehBgKdBLPg-pXSqElt6vrEmQaAukMEALw_wcB

Inside a `.webloc` file, the url works with `&amp;` or without it but not with just the `&` symbol, which it ends up with after copying.

How do I get it copied properly? Without it my `webloc` file doesn't work.

This is part of a Keyboard Maestro macro.

**Edit:**

KM support proposed to me to use a `%ChromeURL%` token instead of the clipboard but the problem persists. Here's the macro:

[image]

I know that this question is about the `clipboard` but both problems seem to be provoked by the same issue. Solving one will prolly solve the other.

Comment: Interesting case for stirring encoding. Is this URL in a pages document or text edit? When I copy that URL from this page using safari app - the ampersand is not encoded here and I presume that’s since it’s a valid ascii character and can be UTF-8 or otherwise encoded (HTML escape in your case) but doesn’t have to be encoded. https://www.url-encode-decode.com/

Comment: In Keyboard Maestro, I create a .webloc file and write `text` to it.

Comment: If you copy the URL manually from Chrome (select in location bar and press cmd-c), and the paste it into a text file, does the full URL get copied?

Comment: @nohillside it gets copied without the `amp;`

Comment: So the problem seems to be rather be with Chrome itself and not related to Keyboard Maestro. Might be helpful to edit the question to avoid answers which focus on the KM part. Do you have an extension installed maybe which removes this part?

Answer (score 1):

I’m not entirely certain how to reproduce this, but if you have this URL passing through keyboard maestro, you could do a search and replace to change the clipboard contents.

https://wiki.keyboardmaestro.com/action/Search_and_Replace

I realize this may not be a good fix if you don’t want to build up all the possible HTML substitutions and this is but one issue you face in a larger problem space.

Comment: Unfortunately not a practical solution since there are far too many url combinations out there to scan for characters. Nonetheless thank you for your effort ;-)

Comment: For sure. It’s never easy with XY type problems where we try to answer how to perform a proposed solution rather than attacking the core issue - an edit of the main post should help people understand why chrome app is putting that string into the pasteboard